# Randomly sample a dataframe in a pre-specified proportion of a column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 100k records. One of the columns `claimed` in the dataframe has only 2 unique values (1 and 2) and it's an 80-20 split in favor of 1.
I'd like to take a random sample of say 10k records (non-repeating) so the resulting dataframe is a balanced dataframe for the column `claimed`.
I looked at [DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) but couldn't find an obvious way to do this.

How can I get a balanced dataframe from an imbalanced dataframe?

Comment: When you mean a pre-specificed proportion, you mean like 50 - 50  odds of grabing the unproportional value?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is to make a equivalent sample, size that is proportional. Even tho you have a skewed data distribution.

I think all I would do is to group by the given classifier column I think in your case it is the claimed one. And select a certain sample size. Like this

```
df.groupby('Claimed')['what_you_want_to_sample'].sample(n = 'the amount you need')
```

That way you would have equivalent sample size for each group.